# Regex expression when order is not is not fixed

Tags: python, regex

I have a data in the form of :

```
{"product": [{ "id": "", "name": "some text", "purchased_at": ""} , {..}, {..}]}
{"product": [{ "name": "", "id": "some text", "purchased_at": ""} , {..}, {..}]}
{"product": [{ "purchased_at": "", "id": "some text", "name": ""} , {..}, {..}]}
...
```

The order of the keys is not fixed, the regex expression I created fails to capture the other data formats:

```
"name":\s*"(.*?)","purchased_at":\s*"(.*?)",.*?"id":\s*"(.*?)"
```

How to I modify this to include the order change?

Comment: Why are you not using dictionary?

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE I'm trying to extract the name , id and purchased at values

Comment: I want to match using regex and then store the groups in dictionary.

Comment: Please mention in your question that you must use regex. Your problem would normally be solved with `json`, and you will be seeing JSON-based solutions.

Comment: Do you want to capture all 3 key/value pairs?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes the values for the 3 keys.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one :

```
(?:{"\w*"\:\s?\[\{\s?)*"(\w*)":\s?"([\w\s]*)"(?:,?\s?\}?\s?\,?\s?\{?\]?\}?)
```

Testing here :
https://regex101.com/r/fDyXMu/1/

Comment: But yes, as this is Json, this format can already being parse by a lot of native python function as @DYZ say in the comment of your question. So Regex is maybe not the best choice, but if you want to use it, do it so :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m = re.search('^(?=.*"name":\s*"(?P<name>.*?)")(?=.*"id":\s*"(?P<id>.*?)")(?=.*"purchased_at":\s*"(?P<purchased_at>.*?)").*', input)
dict = {"name":m.group('name'), "id":m.group('id'), "purchased_at":m.group('purchased_at')}
```

This uses separate look aheads to capture all key/values separately so their order in the input doesn't matter, but *names* the groups so they can be accessed by *name* rather than the usual way by their position.

---

```
>>> m = re.search('^(?=.*"name":\s*"(?P<name>.*?)")(?=.*"id":\s*"(?P<id>.*?)")(?=.*"purchased_at":\s*"(?P<purchased_at>.*?)").*', '{"product": [{ "id": "id1", "name": "name1", "purchased_at": "pa1"} , {..}, {..}]}')
>>> dict={"name":m.group('name'), "id":m.group('id'), "purchased_at":m.group('purchased_at')}
>>> print  dict
{'purchased_at': 'pa1', 'name': 'name1', 'id': 'id1'}
```